# Adicionar 0 aos dias iniciais do mês com Java

Tags: javascript

Alguém poderia me sugerir uma forma de adicionar o "0" aos dias 1, 2, 3 de cada mês transforma-los em 01, 02, 03 seguindo essa estrutura abaixo?

```js
const data = document.querySelector("#dataatual");

const date = new Date();

const dia = Intl.DateTimeFormat("pt-BR",{
    day: "numeric",
});

const mes = Intl.DateTimeFormat("pt-BR",{
    month: "long",
});

const ano = Intl.DateTimeFormat("pt-BR",{
    year: "numeric",
});


data.innerHTML = dia.format(date) + ' de ' + mes.format(date) + ' de ' + ano.format(date);
```

```html
<div id="dataatual"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Esta função adiciona um zero a números menores que 10:

```
function addLeadingZeros(n) {
  if (n <= 9) {
    return "0" + n;
  }
  return n
}
```